# How to make parallel coord plot interactive and more readable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I am trying to make a parallel coordinate graph in R. I want the user to be able to adjust which specific factor level they are viewing data for (album name in this case). Below is my code:

```
ggparcoord(ts, 
           columns = c(3:4, 9, 11:12), 
           groupColumn = 20,
           alphaLines = .75,
           showPoints = TRUE,
           scale = "globalminmax") +
  facet_grid(~ album_name) +
  scale_color_manual("album_name",
                     values = c("#50a7e0", "#ddc477", "#923c81", "#951e1a", "#876b79", "#353839",
                                "hotpink", "#bababa", "#994914", "#f6ed95", "#951e1a"),
                     labels = levels(ts$album_name)) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

The output looks like this:
[image: Plot Output]

As you can see, it is very convoluted and the viewer can't glean much info from it. I want to make it to where the user can select which individual plot they would like to view, without having to use a shiny dashboard (htmlwidgets would be ideal, but I do not know how to implement this well). I am also open to a non interactive solution that might improve readability for the viewer.

Comment: I'm not aware of any widget with which you can "select" one of the panels for a detailed view. But some things come to mind in order to improve the readability of your plot: 1. forget the colors: the variable is already coded in the panel, so it is redundant and adds to the noise. 2. Consider facet_grid(~album_name, cols = 1), so it's stacked instead of wide. 3. Consider having the points and lines with some transparency to improve readability.

Comment: @PavoDive I tried the cols = 1 and got the following error: ```Error in `grid_as_facets_list()`:
! `rows` must be `NULL` or a `vars()` list if `cols` is a `vars()` list``` I tried setting rows to NULL and to a number (11) and got: ``` Error in match.arg(scales, c("fixed", "free_x", "free_y", "free")) : 
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector```

Comment: try `facet_grid(album_name~ .)` instead